# Construction of maps $f:S^3 \to S^2$ with arbitrary Hopf invariant?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

The well-known Hopf fibration $S^1 \rightarrow S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ has explicit constructions involving the geometry of $C^2$ and intersections of complex lines with the $3$-sphere.  They don't seem to generalize easily to "higher" Hopf maps from $S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ with Hopf invariant not equal to one.  Are there any simple expressions for those maps?

Comment: The Seifert fibrations of the three-sphere with generic fiber a $(p,q)$ torus knot described in [(http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248116/are-there-principal-bundles-s1-s3-s2-other-then-hopfs-they-would/248120#248120)] has Hopf invariant $pq$ and also has substantial geometrical meaning, so it might also be of interest to who asked the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get them by precomposing with a degree $n$ map from $S^3$ to itself.  In particular, this gives an interpretation in terms of the group structure: if $h:S^3 \to S^2$ is the Hopf map (which is just modding out by the subgroup $S^1=U(1)$ of $S^3=Sp(1)$, then a map of Hopf invariant n is given by $x \mapsto h(x^n)$, where $x^n$ is using the group multiplication on $S^3$.

Comment: I'd imagine we could equally well post-compose with a degree-n map from S^2 to S^2.

Comment: No, we couldn't compose with S<sup>2</sup> `\to` S<sup>2</sup> map, that map isn't the fibration.

Comment: That's not actually true--it is not true in general that a degree n map on S^k induces multiplication by k on the higher homotopy groups.  Indeed, the Hopf element in \pi_3(S^2) can be written as the Whitehead product [i,i] of the identity i \in \pi_2(S^2).  A degree n map will send this to [ni,ni]=n^2[i,i], not n[i,i].

Answer (score 4):

Actually, yes, there is a construction involving complex projective line.

Consider all points (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) on a 3-sphere in the 4-dimensional space. Our goal is to map them to $S^2$  which is the same as $CP^1$

To do this, take a quaternion

> $$x_1+x_{2}i+x_3j+x_4k$$

raise it to the $n$-th power (this is that group law on a 3-sphere) and decompose back into two complex numbers $z_1+z_2j$ . Now $z_i:z_i$
is a point of a complex projective line, that's it!

Comment: This is the same as my answer, but writing down the group structure explicitly.