# Are there "principal" bundles $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ other then Hopf's? (They would be necessarily not locally trivial)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, principal-bundles

It is well known that the only principal *locally trivial* fiber bundle $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ is Hopf map $h$ (see, for example, [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162506/how-can-i-prove-that-hopf-fibrations-are-the-only-ones-with-fiber-total-space-a)]).

What if we drop the *local triviality* but mantain a *"principality"* hypothesis meaning that the fibers are given by an $S^1$ action? Are there well known families of such bundles $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ whose homotopy class is not that of $h$?

In particular, are the homotopy class of the nontrivial multiples $k[h]$ of Hopf's map in $\pi_3(S^2)$, $k \not\in \{ \pm 1,0 \}$, given by such bundles?

Such bundles would be necessarily *not* locally trivial, but hopefully they can be fibrations.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The 3-sphere has infinitely many Seifert fibrations with generic
fiber a torus knot (including the unknot).

[image: Seifert fibration of 3-sphere]

For a [$(p,q)$ torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot), the [Hopf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant) will be $pq$ (up to sign).
To see this, note that the fibration has two exceptional fibers
which form the Hopf link (these are the red line and yellow circle in the image). The generic fibers wrap $p$ times
around one of these, and $q$ times around the other, so have
linking number $pq$.

In fact, then, one can represent each homotopy class in $\pi_3(S^2)$ by
a Seifert fibration with a single exceptional fiber (so all fibers are
unknots, generically a $(p,1)$ curve on the [Clifford torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus)).

These are (non-locally trivial) ``principal bundles" in the sense that there is an action of $S^1$ whose orbits are the fibers of the fibration. If $S^3\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ as the unit sphere, then the action is $(z_1,z_2)\to (z^pz_1,z^qz_2)$, for $z\in S^1= \{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1\}$.

Comment: Fantastic @IanAgol ! This is was the kind of answer I was expecting, the picture was a nice bonus. Do you know a reference for these constructions?

Comment: This is a really beautiful answer, but I still must object to the misuse of the word 'bundle', which to me means locally trivial.

Comment: @MarkGrant: agreed, but I would blame the poser of the question for using bundle improperly (and he makes it clear that the bundle need not be locally trivial). The fibration is a Seifert fibration, and can be regarded as a principal bundle over an orbifold; however, of course, the orbifold structure on the base is being forgotten to get $S^2$.

Comment: Thanks again @IanAgol! Personally I feel that these examples should always be given when one remarks that the Hopf map generates $\pi_3(S^2)$, don't you think?

Comment: @MarkGrant I see your point and I kind of agree: I thought of using "principal maps" in the title and text of the question, instead of "principal bundles that are not locally trivial". I did not do it since I haven't seen the name "principal map" used elsewhere, but I am very open to suggestions for improving the question.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that, although the fibers are given by an $S^1$ action, that action is not free on two of the fibers. On $z_1=0$ and $z_2=0$, the action has a finite (nontrivial) stabilizer. Basically, you are exploiting that $S^1$ is a finite cover of itself.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I consider these kind of geometric construction a real pearl. It's not easy to find geometric structures with neat functional definitions and yet being non trivial in some sense!